# How to write netcdf files with multiple variables?

Tags: raster, r, netcdf

I'm using `raster stack` objects and I want to use `multiple stacks` and write them in a single `netcdf` file. In case of `one stack` its straight forward as the below example, but how can I have both of the stacks in the same file as different `variables`?

```
library("raster")
r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
s1 <- stack(r, r*2)
s2 <- stack(r*3, r*4)

writeRaster(s1, file="stk.nc",varname="var1",longname="var1_name", varunit="unit", xname="lon", yname="lat" ,zname="zname",format="CDF", overwrite=T,datatype='INT2S')
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this with raster. You'll need to learn how to drive ncdf4 (or RNetCDF), it's tedious but not too complicated. There are a few wrapper packages on CRAN, worth searching to see if any have an easy multi-var write. Probably you should get one of the command line utilties and use those to combine .nc files, rather than R, though.  You can't really do proper NetCDF with either raster or GDAL FYI, they are both great for reading but not writing.

Comment: Without learning `ncdf4`, you could save different files then merge them with `nco` or `cdo` via `system()`. But yeah, `ncdf4` would be the best way to do it.

Comment: Maybe this https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/easyNCDF/index.html